# how to shared object data between two component using service(rxjs subject )

Tags: angular

Please give me a solution for that question. I want to pass a custom object using service.

```
private  messageSource = new Subject<Add>();
changeMessage(message:Add) {
    console.log(message);
    this.messageSource.next(message)
    console.log(this.messageSource);
    //console.log(this.currentMessage);
}
getMessage():Observable<Add>{
    return this.messageSource.asObservable();
}

class Add {
    success:boolean;
    status:string;
    id:string;
    imgArray:string[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subject inside your service

```
messageSource: Subject<string>;
```

and instantiate inside your constructor

```
this.messageSource = new Subject<string>();
```

in your component you can do this,

```
this.yourService.messageSource.next('whatvermessage');
```

and if you want to subscribe to it, you can do

```
this.yourService.messageSource.asObservable().subscribe((value: string) => {

});
```

Comment: can i pass any object using Subject

Comment: i passed  the value to changeMessage() methode form my parent file like bellow .it came to  changeMessage() methode.but this.messageSource.next(message) is not working

Comment: how can i chat with u.comments are not allowed