# How do you update a certain component's view when dealing with multiple views?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient

So I have an Angular app with multiple components.

One of the components is a navigation bar, which consists of user and admin dropdown menus.

How do I update the main view (the body) to dynamically `XHR GET` load another URL? My XHR GET code is already done with `HttpClient`. `<div [innerHtml]="dashboardData"></div>` doesn't work apparently.

Here is an example of my XHR code:

```
fetchDashboard() {


    const requestOptions: object = {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Bearer Tokenhere'),
      responseType: 'text'
    };
    this.http.get<string>('http://localhost:3000/dashboard',
        requestOptions)
            .subscribe(response => {
                   console.log(response);
                   // this should get used to update the view
                   this.dashboardData = response;
            }
    );
}
```

I got recommended [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/21/angular-8-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) but I don't know how to implement it for my use case.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561255/how-to-update-view-from-another-component-in-angular-7/57561421#57561421), but my question needs a different solution.

Comment: so, what is your error statement here

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I get no error and my view doesn't show the intended content. I would also like to *completely replace* the content in the view

Answer (score 1):

You can create service to share data between your views using a RxJS `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`.

e.g

`your.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  private sharedSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<YourDataType>(<YourDataType>{})


  public shareData(data: YourDataType): void {
    this.sharedSubject$.next(data);
  }

  public getSharedData(): Observable<YourDataType> {
    return this.sharedSubject$.asObservable()
  }

}
```

Inside your method  `fetchDashboard()` following do:

```
fetchDashboard() {
 ...

  this.http.get<string>('http://localhost:3000/dashboard',
        requestOptions)
            .subscribe(response => {
                   console.log(response);
                   // this should get used to update the view
                   this.dashboardData = response;
                   this.yourShareService.shareData(response);
            }
    );

}
```

And in your other component just subscribe using `getSharedData()` and update your view as soon as the data as been updated.

For the subscription inside your component you can do something like this:

`this.yourSharedService.getSharedData().subscribe(data => {
   this.dashboardData = data;
})`

Comment: I tried this without any avail: `ngOnInit() {console.log('dashboardData: ', this.dashboardData);
  this.shareData.getSharedData().subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
  });


  }`

Comment: The code doesn't appear to change the view. Please check out the related question, which contains the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952820/how-to-import-dynamic-xhr-content-into-a-template-dynamically/58953746?noredirect=1#comment104167995_58953746

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this [Stack Blitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfj2sx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Your Json structure is ...

```
[
  {"id":1,"name":"Pencil"}, 
  {"id":2,"name":"Pen"}
]
```

your getData()..

```
getData(){
  return this.httpClient.get('/assets/data.json') .pipe(
   tap (data => this.data$.next(data))
  )
}
```

Your subject is...

```
  private data$ : Subject <any> = new Subject <any>();
```

Your ngOnInit() is...

```
ngOnInit(){ 
   this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data =>{
       this.data= data;
   })
   this.dataService.data$.subscribe(data =>{
       this.data = data;
   })
}
```

here, first default data is loaded with two data of json using http.get(), then you have to click sendData button then this.data$ observable is set with your new data and we get those data in component by subscribing to it in ngOnInit() method.

Comment: I am working with HTML and not JSON.. I would select your answer if it were to expand upon the other answer, since that answer already does 80% of the needed job

Comment: you can bind json data back to html using string interpolation.